# How to link feature files with step definition in CodeceptJS?

Tags: phpstorm, gherkin, codeceptjs

I'm trying to implement the BDD framework in CodeceptJS using PHPStorm as my IDE. But for some reason it is not recognising the step definitions and in the feature file it shows the error

> Undefined step reference

I followed the steps given in the CodeceptJS documentation such as `codeceptjs gherkin:init` (which implemented the gherkins module) and `codeceptjs gherkin:snippets` (which implements the step definition automatically)
I'm running on

- MacOS
- CodeceptJS on PHPStorm
- Selenium Server with ChromeDriver

My codecept.conf.js file

```js
exports.config = {
  output: './output',
  helpers: {
    WebDriver: {
      smartWait: 10000,
      url: 'my_url',
      browser: 'chrome'
    }
  },
  include: {
    I: './steps_file.js',
    assignmentsPage: './pages/AssignmentsPageObject.js'
  },
  mocha: {},
  bootstrap: null,
  teardown: null,
  hooks: [],
  gherkin: {
    features: './features/*.feature',
    steps: ['./step_definitions/steps.js']
  },
  plugins: {
    screenshotOnFail: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },
  tests: './*_test.js',
  name: 'AssignmentsClient'
}
```

I expect the framework to detect the step defintion corresponding to the various scenarios mentioned in the feature file.

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The reason why the BDD framework wasn't being recognised is because PHPStorm doesn't support a cucumber plugin. So it shows undefined only in the IDE. Once you start running the tests from the terminal, it gets recognised and works accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

CodeceptJS is not currently supported, please vote for [WEB-31128](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31128) to be notified on any progress with this feature

Comment: Thank you so much Lena! Much appreciated!